# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append': Key and list value dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

When I try to append a value to a key dictionary, it gives me this error
Which I dont understand why

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

here my code

```
def create_dict():
    MessageReceived_Dict = {}
    with open("message_logs.csv", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        csvreader = csv.reader(f)
        for item in csvreader:

            Message_Date = item[0]
            Number = item[1]
            MessageReceived = item[2]

            with open("info_log.json", "r+") as f:
                data = json.load(f)
                for round in data["Round"]:
                    if Number in round["AllNumber"]:
                        if MessageReceived in round["MessageReceived"]:
                            print("Message Already in Json File")
                        else:
                            if Message_Date not in MessageReceived_Dict:
                                MessageReceived_Dict[Message_Date] = MessageReceived
                            else:
                                MessageReceived_Dict[Message_Date].append(MessageReceived)
    print(MessageReceived_Dict)
```

The output that I am looking for:

```
{"2022-08-18": ["No thanks", "Ok", "Yes"], "2022-08-19": ["Why", "No"]}
```

Comment: The value of ``MessageReceived_Dict[Message_Date]`` is a string. You are trying to append to a string which is not possible. This is what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
MessageReceived_Dict[Message_Date] = MessageReceived
```

to

```
MessageReceived_Dict[Message_Date] = [MessageReceived]
```

in order to have the values in the dictionaries be lists of messages instead of messages, allowing appending subsequent messages to them.